# N-Series Virtual Machine not available on bizspark subscription

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

I have a Bizspark Subscription with Rs.10,000 in credit. I want to setup a GPU with N-Series Virtual Machine. But it is showing "This size is not available in the location for the subscription." Even after entering the appropriate regions shown on [Azure Products by Region](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/regions/services/)

Why is this happening?

Also my partner had been using NV-12 Virtual Machine from 3 months with Bizspark Subscription.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could be restricted by Azure to certain regions, say only south east asia. Create a support ticket to lift that limitation and\or learn the exact set of regions you are allowed to use